# Increase columns in Pander

Tags: r, pander

So I have a 6 column dataframe I want to display in an email. Everything is set up correctly but it displays only 5 columns and the 6th one down below. Is there a fix?

I am using pander and sendMailR in this code.

Thanks,

NC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, the [general options](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#general-options) are your best friend when it comes to `pander`:

```
> panderOptions('table.split.table', Inf)
> pander(head(iris))

-------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sepal.Length   Sepal.Width   Petal.Length   Petal.Width   Species 
-------------- ------------- -------------- ------------- ---------
     5.1            3.5           1.4            0.2       setosa  

     4.9             3            1.4            0.2       setosa  

     4.7            3.2           1.3            0.2       setosa  

     4.6            3.1           1.5            0.2       setosa  

      5             3.6           1.4            0.2       setosa  

     5.4            3.9           1.7            0.4       setosa  
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Probably I'll make this as the default value in the next release of `pander` not to confuse first time users.

Comment: Awesome. I've been at work all day and my brain is about to stop working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would have just gone with `pander(iris, split.table = Inf)` -- Not sure about the idea to make `Inf` the default value in the next release though. I guess it won't break anything, so it should be fine. (+1, of course).

Comment: Hmm, I'll take that into consideration @AnandaMahto , but it shouldn't make too much of a difference. Now the only problem I am having is the format looks weird. The last (6th) column "header" is pushed out to the right.

Comment: @NealC this sounds really strange. Can you share a reproducible minimal example of the problem and [open an issue on GH](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/issues)?

Comment: I can't really release information. I think it's because I'm using pander.return() so I can put it in an email... Do you know a fix around that?

Comment: @NealC `pander.return` is basically a wrapper around `pander` calling `capture.output` and `paste`, so this should not cause modify the structure of the markdown table. About the minimal reproducible example: no need to release any of your data, probably you can generate some dummy data (with `runif`, `letters` etc.) resulting in the exact same erroneous symptom.

Comment: Sorry, took a while to set up example data, but this is how it show's up in the email. I put a pic on imgur, hope thats okay with the StackOverflow "gods". [link](http://imgur.com/WLUFi8n)

Comment: @NealC this looks strange because the markdown table is shown with a non-monospaced (fixed-width) font. Either use a fixed-width font in your HTML mail (`font-family` CSS), or transform the markdown table to HTML. An alternative solution would be setting your mail client to render mails with monospaced fint.

Comment: Alright, thank you for all the information you provided. Just got back from Christmas break to work, but we got the table to work right before we left. :)